# How to navigate from an ActionSheet action to another view?

Tags: navigation, swiftui

I have an ActionSheet and I don't know how to make navigation to another view from the action sheet callback button.

```swift
let action = ActionSheet.Button.cancel {
     //navigation???       
}
ActionSheet(title: Text("some title"), buttons: [action])
```

I.E: I would like to have this as a chooser when selecting images from different sources: camera or camera roll.

Answer (score 4):

This is how you can achieve this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isSheet: Bool = false
    @State var isPresented: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Button(dict.description) {
                self.isSheet = true
            }.actionSheet(isPresented: $isSheet) {
                ActionSheet(title: Text("Some title"), message: nil, buttons: [
                    .default(Text("Present view")) {
                        self.isPresented = true
                    },
                    .cancel()
                ])
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Home"))
            .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented, content: { Text("This is another view!") })
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of `.sheet`, you can also use `.popover`